# Sip Servlet Creates Faulty Responses (Contact Field)

Tags: sip, jain-sip

I'm trying to send a 200 OK response using a Sip Servlet after an Invite request by using request.createResponse(200).

Problem is that the Contact header comes out without the "username" part.
Why is this happening?

### Relevant Code:

```
protected void doInvite(SipServletRequest arg0) throws ServletException, IOException {

    SipServletResponse respRinging = arg0.createResponse(180);

    respRinging.send();

    SipServletResponse respOk = arg0.createResponse(200);   

    String sdpData = "v=0\r\n" +
                     "o=- 2 2 IN IP4 192.168.50.18\r\n" +
                     "s=Testing V1.0\r\n" +
                     "c=IN IP4 192.168.50.18\r\n" + 
                     "t=0 0\r\n" + 
                     "m=audio 63364 RTP/AVP 18 101\r\n" +
                     "a=fmtp:18 annexb=yes\r\n" +
                     "a=fmtp:101 0-15\r\n" +
                     "a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000\r\n" +
                     "a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\r\n" +
                     "a=sendrecv\r\n";

    byte[] contents = sdpData.getBytes(); 

    respOk.setContent(contents, arg0.getContentType()); 

    respOk.send();              
}
```

### Created 200 Message:

```
%dMES%22=SIP/2.0 200 OK
Call-ID: ZDE4MzY3NzAzNjRlN2UwZDBmMGZlNDA1MTNlZWJiOWE.
CSeq: 1 INVITE
From: 6000 <sip:6000@192.168.50.18>;tag=d765eb39
To: 2451 <sip:2451@192.168.50.18>;tag=9020141091761795_local.1330939329531_17_16
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.50.201:57332;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-cc352300a144627e-1---d8754z-;rport=57332;received=192.168.50.201
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 221
Contact: sip:IP-HOST:5060;transport=udp
```

I expected the Contact URI to be `sip:2451@IP-HOST:5060;transport=udp`

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that jain-sip is automatically populating the Contact URI. It's a perfectly valid Contact URI - the username is not required.

If you need to specify a particular URI, have you tried `respOk.addHeader("Contact", "My sip:special@uri:5060")`?